# Anchor tag not working inside absolutely positioned div

Tags: css, css-position

I have created an unordered list inside a div which is absolutely positioned. When I add an `href` inside of the `li` items, it's not working.

For example: `<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>` is still not clickable.

Here is the CSS (the nav is the wrapping div):

```
#nav
{
    background:#666666;
    position:absolute;
    top: 270px;
    left:150px;
    height:40px;
}
#nav ul li 
{
    position:relative;
    top:-8px;
    left: -15px;
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 33px;
    font-size:14px;
    border-right: 2px solid #333333;    
    margin:auto;
    color: #efefef;
}
```

Here's the full code. I also figured out that some other element is overlapping, but don't know what to do.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Good Brothers Film Entertainment</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
              <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo2.png" id="logo2"/>
                <img src="images/logo.png"/>         
              </div>

              <div id="nav">
               <ul>
                 <li><span>H</span>OME</li>
                 <li><span>S</span>ERVICES</li>
                 <li><span>R</span>EELS</li>
                 <li><span>G</span>ALLERY</li>
                 <li><span>A</span>BOUT US</li>
                 <li><span>C</span>ONTACTS</li>
                 <li><span>A</span>FFILIATES</li>
               </ul>
              </div>
             </div>
              <img src="images/inner-background.png" id="inner-background" />
            <p id="welcome">~<span>W</span>ELCOME~</p> 
            <img src="images/good-brother.png" id="good-brother"/>
            <img src="images/working-together.png" class="work-together" />
            <img src="images/and.png" class="work-together" />
            <img src="images/exceeding-limits.png" class="work-together" />
            <img src="images/men.png" class="men" />
            <img src="images/men-shadow.png" class="men" />
            <img src="images/footer.png" id="footer" />
            <div id="video">
              <!--  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/V0LQnQSrC-g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

The CSS
body,html{margin:0;border:0;padding:0;}

#container
{
   width:1360px;
   height:1024px;
   background:url(../images/background.png);
}

#logo2
{
  position:absolute;    
}

#nav
{
    background:#666666;
    position:absolute;
    top: 270px;
    left:150px;
    height:40px;
}
#nav ul li 
{
    position:relative;
    top:-8px;
    left: -15px;
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 33px;
    font-size:14px;
    border-right: 2px solid #333333;    
    margin:auto;
    color: #efefef;
}
#nav li span
{
    font-size: 21px;
}
#nav li:last-child
{
    border:none;
}
#inner-background
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
#welcome
{
    color:#ffffff;
    top:300px;
    left:300px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    position:absolute;
}
#welcome span
{
    font-size: 28px;
}
#good-brother
{
  top:1px;
  position:absolute;    
}
.work-together
{
    top: -5px;
    position:absolute;
}
#video
{
 top: 400px;
 left:600px;
 height:315px;
 width:560px;
 background: #eeeeee;
 position: absolute;

}
.men,#footer
{
    top:1px;
     position: absolute;    
}
```

Comment: This problem happening on all browser?

Comment: Please provide your HTML markup that you're styling.

Comment: actually it works: http://jsfiddle.net/EcyHP/. Probably you have some another element whitch is overlap your menu.

Comment: Post update: [Still seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/EcyHP/2/), although I had to add the `<a>` for you. Probably best to make a live demo that shows your problem.

Comment: Your updated version also functions: http://jsfiddle.net/EcyHP/3/. Could you offer us a link to your page? Also, what browser/environment are you using?

Comment: thanks guys. as kraz pointed out, it was the problem with images overlapping with the div. I just sliced'em out from a PSD and absolutely positioned them on the page. Will this create problems in older browsers in terms of their layout, say IE6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Still work with the complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/HgTpC/), but with no images.

I suspect that your problem is the `#footer` image
(I can confirm it is if the image is over 300 pixel high!)

Here's why :

```
.men,#footer
{
    top:1px;
     position: absolute;    
}
```

Since this image is defined **after**, it's put on top. It's either that image or another one big enough to cover your header.

This css declaration could help find if an image is the culprit :

```
img {border:3px solid red !important;}
```

If you have firebug or other similar developpement tool, right click on your link and do **inspect element** : if you have an element over it, it should be selected.

*Note* : if you dont have firebug or something similar... Get one asap.

Comment: hey kraz, u got it spot on. Its the footer thats the culprit. So what should I do to make display properly?

Comment: It's a footer... So go for `#footer {bottom:0px;}` instead of _top:0px_... :) (but still, be careful when using absolute/fixed positionning!)

Comment: so what is the best way to position a sliced image from PSD or is it better just to save it? I'm a PHP programmer getting into CSS lately. I thought the transparency would make the job easier. Turns out that a number of images overlap the nav div. How would you do this if you were doing this from scratch?

Comment: To be honest, since you stated that you were starting, you simply need to learn more CSS and how it works! There's no "perfect" way. Good practice is usually about positionning your item from top to bottom and putting small item in large one. It's pretty much impossible to explain that in such few words. I'd suggest you to  grab some nice website template from the web and look at the code. Finally, try to reduce the size and number of pictures if possible :)

Comment: thank u man. i didnt know the footer was bigger than the original logo ..lol...i am going through http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-convert-a-psd-to-xhtml/  .Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your layout, you can use z-index set to a high enough value allowing the anchor tags to overcome the overlapping element.